# rendering sub-categories per category in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

if i have a stateless functional component that receives props and has to categorise the data: display it according to categories , each categories will have subcategories how will i render it. My code looks like below:

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

const IndicatorSelector = props => {
  const indicators = props.indicators || [];
  console.log(indicators);

  return indicators
    .sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name)
    .map((indicator, index) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <ul className="checkBox">
            <li className="list">
              <input
                key={`${index}`}
                type="checkbox"
                name={indicator}
                className="checkInput"
              />
              <label for="indicator">{indicator.type}</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    });
};
export default IndicatorSelector;
```

Comment: I want to render types per names. hence category: Name SubCategory : Types

Comment: Can you provide sample data and sample output.

Comment: {
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Gini Measure",
      "type": "Disposable Gini"
    },
    {
      "name": "Gini Measure",
      "type": "Market Gini"
    },
    {
      "name": "Gini Measure",
      "type": "Absolute Redistribution"
    },
    {
      "name": "Gini Measure",
      "type": "Relative Redistribution"
    }
  ] this has to be categorised according to names. 1 name will have many types

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) from `lodash` to categorise according to `names`.
First parameter will be an Array/Object. Second parameter will be a function to transform keys. In your case, since you need to groupBy `name`, you need to return `name` from function.

```
    _.groupBy([ { "name": "Gini Measure", "type": "Disposable Gini" }, { "name": "Gini Measure", "type": "Market Gini" }, { "name": "Gini Measure", "type": "Absolute Redistribution" }, { "name": "Gini Measure", "type": "Relative Redistribution" } ], 
(x) => x.name);
```

Output:

```
{"Gini Measure":[{"name":"Gini Measure","type":"Disposable Gini"},{"name":"Gini Measure","type":"Market Gini"},{"name":"Gini Measure","type":"Absolute Redistribution"},{"name":"Gini Measure","type":"Relative Redistribution"}]}
```

Considering that you want to render sub-categories, you can do it like below:

```
const IndicatorSelector = props => {
  const indicators = props.indicators || [];
  const grouped = _.groupBy(indicators, x => x.name);
  return Object.keys(grouped).
    .map(x => {
      return (
        <div>
          <label for="indicator">{x}</label>
          {grouped[x].map((obj, index) => (
            <ul className="checkBox">
            <li className="list">
              <input
                key={`${index}`}
                type="checkbox"
                name={obj}
                className="checkInput"
              />
              <label for="indicator">{obj.type}</label>
            </li>
          </ul>)
          )}
        </div>
      );
    });
};
export default IndicatorSelector;
```